# Setting up deadlines for a time sensitive workflow

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer, email, sharepoint-enterprise

I'm creating a typical three state workflow where the Approver must approve after a certain number of days.

It was suggested that these deadlines for the Approver shouldn't be set from the workflow, but rather the deadlines be set through the the Task List through emails.

This is the end result I'm looking for. 
If the task hasn't been opened at all by the Approver for three days, a reminder email.
After five days, an email to Approver and Approver's supervisor.

If the task has been opened but not yet completed, then the Approver has fifteen days from when the task first landed on the Approver's desk.

Does the task list notification sound ideal or should I seek another method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create secondary workflows on your task list that fire on item creation to evaluate the status of the task.

Basiclly, you'd pause for 3 days in the first step.  Then in step 2, you'd look at the Status of the workflow task.  If it's in the default state, you'd send an email to the user.  If not, pause for 2 days.  Then you'd do the same evaluation and email the supervisor and user.

The issue with this is that there isn't really a means to "track" whether they've opened it.  The only reasonable way in this context is upon getting the notification of the task, the user acknowledges it by updating the status to In Progress or something.

[Nintex](http://nintex.com) offers a Flexitask action in their workflow product that handles reminders and things like that if you're looking for a third party tool.

Comment: I'll have to look at the Flexitask option. Thanks.